# Basic ERD analysis for a martial arts business domain

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I am working on a basic website in order to support querying results from martial arts tournament data. We use participation data to determine things like who gets to host tournaments, regional awards, etc.

Example queries would be along the lines of:

- Total participants by school per tournament
- Total participants by school owner (Owners can have multiple schools)
- Top performing school (participant placing)
- Most heavily entered age/rank divisions
- Total entries per event

**My current diagram**

I have the following entity relationship diagram (ERD) (With the tournament "table" being truncated, there are 27 attributes that include rank, bracket, placing in each event, name, age, etc). It's fairly simple, but at this point I think it is all I need. (Future advancements will include analysis of judging participation, etc).

[image]

**Questions**

- For the ERD, do I necessarily need the one-to-many (1:M) relationship indicator between the school table and the results table? They will be used in queries, but are not necessarily tied to each other.
- And, is the basic diagram correct in its layout?